# How to fix error Incorrect syntax near '+' xp_cmdshell and OPENROWSET

Tags: sql, ssms

First time posting, thank you in advance for help. I am trying to import XLSX files directly and dynamically into a SQL server DB. The XLSX filename is used to create a table name and the first row in the first sheet is used to generate the column names.
Goal is to load raw data received into a table, and to then utilise transformation logic to conform the raw data into the correct structure and place it within a final table which can be reported on and exported again.

This raw data will always be received in xlsx, however the columns names will change slightly with each import.

This is using xp_cmdshell and openrowset, my sql for these lines being -

```
INSERT INTO @files (FilePath)
EXEC xp_cmdshell 'DIR ' + QUOTENAME(@folderPath, '''') + '*.xlsx /B /A:-D'
```

and

```
    INSERT INTO #tempTable (ColumnName, ColumnData)
    SELECT * FROM OPENROWSET('Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0', 'Excel 12.0;Database=' + QUOTENAME(@filePath, '''') + ';HDR=YES', 'SELECT * FROM [Sheet1$]')
```

The Import/Export wizard appears to only allow one xlsx file at a time, so I will need to use T-SQL to achieve a consistent and intuitive approach

When I attempt to run my script I am given this same syntax error on both of those lines

"Incorrect syntax near '+'."

I have attempted to fix this with concat(), but I don't believe this functions with xp_cmdshell or with OPENROWSET.

I have tried using ChatGPT to correct my errors however it doesn't seem able to determine why this script is reporting syntax errors.

Thanks, I have never attempted this concept before and am rusty with my SQL.

Comment: Those values for OPENROWSET do need to be string constants (read up at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/openrowset-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16).  You may need to use some dynamic SQL, but there's some considerations with that if you want to use a temporary table (it would either need to be a global temp table, or just use a static staging table - provided you're not expecting processes to run in parallel with each other and load up data into the same staging table)

Comment: Alternatively, do you have the option of using an SSIS package?  That might be a more practical alternative for you

Answer (score 0):

I've found that working with stuff like OpenRowSet  it's best to go ahead and create a variable for the entire string.  Something like:

```
set @Str = 'DIR ' + QUOTENAME(@folderPath, '''') + '*.xlsx /B /A:-D'
EXEC xp_cmdshell @str
```

But, I'm not sure why you need to use xp_cmdshell.  I believe you could do the same thing that I did when I imported jpegs of my database diagrams.   Of course, you'd have to modify it a little for xlsx files, but the concept should be the same.

```
truncate table dbd.DictionaryDiagrams--Just getting the diagram names into a table
insert into dbd.DictionaryDiagrams(DiagramName, MimeType)
select name DiagramName, 'image/jpeg' MimeType from dbo.sysdiagrams;

---Loop through all the names and import the jpegs
declare c cursor for
    select DiagramName from dbd.DictionaryDiagrams
open c
    declare @Path nvarchar(500), @Directory nvarchar(30), @Diagram 
    nvarchar(200), @sql nvarchar(max)
set @Directory = '\\ServerName\DictionaryDiagrams\'
fetch next from c into @Diagram
set @Path = @Directory + @Diagram + '.jpg'
set @sql = 'update dbd.DictionaryDiagrams set Diagram = ' + 
           '(select * from openrowset(bulk N''' + @Path + ''', Single_blob) as 
           Diagram) ' + 'where DiagramName = ''' + @Diagram + '''' + ';'
exec (@sql)

while @@fetch_status = 0 
begin
    fetch next from c into @Diagram
     set @Path = @Directory + @Diagram + '.jpg'
     set @sql = 'update dbd.DictionaryDiagrams set Diagram = ' + 
           '(select * from openrowset(bulk N''' + @Path + ''', Single_blob) as 
           Diagram) ' + 'where DiagramName = ''' + @Diagram + '''' + ';'
exec (@sql)
end
close c
deallocate c
```

---

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/import-export/import-data-from-excel-to-sql?view=sql-server-ver16

```
USE ImportFromExcel;
GO
SELECT * INTO Data_dq
FROM OPENROWSET('Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0',
    'Excel 12.0; Database=C:\Temp\Data.xlsx', [Sheet1$]);
GO
```

---

Before trying to get all the files, just get one working.  Then you can put all of them inside a while loop.